# Natural sorting in MS SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql-server, sorting, sql-server-2012

I need help with natural sorting in SQL Server 2012. I have `varchar` column with values :

```
PAZ/01/03/2014
...
PAZ/233/03/2014
PAZ/01/04/2014
....
PAZ 10/04/2014
...
PAZ/100/04/2014
```

where `PAZ` is static string, the second part after / is the lp number (start from 01 in each month -3 rd part), and last part is a year.

When I sort by this column I receive for example

```
PAZ/01/04/2014
PAZ/02/04/2014
...
PAZ 10/04/2014
PAZ 02/04/2014
```

but I need natural sorting (by lp in each months)

```
PAZ/01/03/2014
...
PAZ233/03/2014
PAZ/01/04/2014
PAZ/02/04/2014
...
PAZ/10/04/2014
...
PAZ/300/04/2014
PAZ/01/05/2014
...
PAZ/500/05/2014
etc
```

Comment: If the component parts of this are needed for sorting, querying, etc, it tends to point to the fact that the components ought to be stored in separate columns. Then this varchar could be constructed by e.g. a computed column.

Answer (score -1):

if i was in your situation i will create new column and insert the date part in ip string into it , i.e.

```
COLUMN 1               Column 2 
PAZ/01/03/2014          03/2014
PAZ/233/03/2014         03/2014
PAZ/01/04/2014          04/2014
PAZ/02/04/2014          04/2014
```

then order result by column 2,column 1

P.S. you can use patindex to cut ip string and create new column

Comment: This will still sort `PAZ/101/03/2014` before `PAZ/12/03/2014`

Comment: so create third column that only contains the IP part 
and order by column2,column3,column1